# Proof (or reference) about $\lambda_i(A+\epsilon e_je_j^*) = \lambda_i(A) + \epsilon |v_{i,j}|^2 + O(\epsilon^2).$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I'm looking for a proof (or a reference in a textbook) about the fact that
$$
\lambda_i(A+\epsilon e_je_j^*) =_{\epsilon \to 0} \lambda_i(A) + \epsilon |v_{i,j}|^2 + O(\epsilon^2),
$$
where $A$ is an hermitian matrix, $\lambda_i(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $e_j \in \bf{R}^n$ is defined by $(e_j)_i = \delta_{i,j}$, $v_{i,j}$ is the $j-$th component of a unit eigenvector of $\lambda_i(A)$.

This theorem is from perturbation theory, a field I'm not very familiar with.

This is used in : Peter B. Denton, Stephen J. Parke, Terence Tao and Xining Zhang. $\textit{Eigenvectors from eigenvalues: A survey of a basic identity in linear algebra}, 2021;$
[arXiv:1908.03795](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) (page $13$).

Comment: Queries with keywords "eigenvalues rank-one update" bring interesting information like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325484}).

Comment: See as well [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0618.pdf).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your answer but I don't see how they help :/ (I read both of them)

Comment: All right. I didn't know your acquaintance with the field. Maybe from the same Terry Tao : https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/when-are-eigenvalues-stable/

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your link, I think that equation $(5)$ is what I was looking for.

Comment: cross-posted https://mathoverflow.net/a/392665/11260