# Spectral radius bound for a rank-1 update

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory, linear-control

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and let $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. Suppose we know the following:
$$
A\text{ has an eigenvalue at $1$},\quad
\rho(A) = 1,
\quad\text{and}\quad
\rho(A + uv^\top) = \eta < 1.
$$
In the case where $n=1$, we have $A=1$ and $u$ and $v$ are scalars, which implies that $uv = \pm\eta-1$.

I'm trying to find a relationship between $u,v$ and $\eta$ for general $n$. I'm not sure what it would look like exactly, but my hope is that $v^\top u$ should be related to $\eta$ somehow.

In general, under mild conditions, adding an arbitrary rank-1 matrix to $A$ can move its eigenvalues anywhere we choose (see [Two matrices that are not similar have (almost) same eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320509/two-matrices-that-are-not-similar-have-almost-same-eigenvalues/3320761#3320761) and [Eigenvalues of rank-$1$ update](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322346/eigenvalues-of-rank-1-update)), so simply knowing the eigenvalues of $A$ doesn't tell us anything about the eigenvalues of the perturbed $A$. However, this case is different: I know something about the eigenvalues of $A$ *and* the perturbed $A$, and I'd like to deduce something about the size of the perturbation.

My first effort to simplify the problem was to assume a diagonal $A$ (which can be done without loss of generality if $A$ is diagonalizable), but I wasn't able to make much progress.

Comment: A rough upper bound is given by $|v^Tu|=|\operatorname{tr}(A)-\operatorname{tr}(A+uv^T)|\le|\operatorname{tr}(A)|+|\operatorname{tr}(A+uv^T)|\le n(1+\eta)$.

Comment: oh nice --- and this same technique can be used to get a lower bound of $n(1-\eta)$, if I'm not mistaken... oh nevermind. I don't think that works.