# Eigenvalue relation of a symmetric matrix $A$ and $A + vv^T$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, projection-matrices, hermitian-matrices

My question pertains to the material in the book "The Algebraic Eigenvalue Problem" by J.H.  Wilkinson. Section "Symmetric matrix of rank unity", pages 96-97.

The setup is as follows. We have a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $B = vv^T$ is a rank one projector. It is possible to show that there exists an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that
$$
Q^T(A + B)Q = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & b^T \\
b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho & O \\
O & O \\
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}
$$
Here $\rho$ is a non-zero eigenvalue of $B$, $O$ denotes blocks of zeroes, $\alpha$ is a scalar and $\text{diag}(\alpha_i)$ is a diagonal submatrix.

The eigenvalue of $A$ denoted as $\lambda_i(A)$ and eigenvalue $\lambda_i(A+B)$ of $A+B$ are therefore those of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & b^T \\
b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\
\end{bmatrix} \textrm{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha + \rho & b^T \\
b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{2}
$$

The claim is that $\lambda_i(A+B)$ satisfies the following relation:
$$
\lambda_i(A+B) = \lambda_i(A) + m_i \rho,
$$
where $0 \leq m_i \leq 1$ and $\sum m_i = 1.$

I don't understand where this $m_i$ comes from and why all $m_i \in [0,1]$ add up to 1? How does this follow from (1) and (2)?

Comment: what is $\text{diag}(\alpha_i) ?$ is $\alpha$ a scalar ? So $O$ is of dimension $n-1\times n-1 ?$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I introduced clarifications in the post.

Comment: no but what is $\alpha_i$ ? It makes it look like you are using eigen-decomposition of $A$ and $B$ separately when you talk about $\lambda_i(A)$ etc. But at the same time the $Q^T(A+B)Q$ is not guaranteed to work for both.

Comment: I am particularly curious of the line: The eigenvalue of $A$ denoted as $\lambda_i(A)$ and eigenvalue $\lambda_i(A+B)$ of $A+B$ are therefore those of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & b^T \\
b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\
\end{bmatrix} \textrm{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha + \rho & b^T \\
b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{2}
$$
)

Comment: I clarified that $\text{diag}(\alpha_i)$ is a diagonal submatrix of $A$. This diagonal submatrix is the result of $Q^TAQ$.

Comment: $Q$ diagonalizes $B$, but does not diagonalize $A$, therefore we get $Q^TAQ = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & b^T \\ b & \text{diag}(\alpha_i) \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: In that case, [Gerschgorin's circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) should be very close if not give you what you want.

In general, there is no analytic or closed formula for the eigenvalues of a matrix that is rank 1 perturbation of a given symmetric matrix, in terms of the eigenvalues the said given matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q^TAQ = A_1$ and $Q^TBQ = B_1.$  Consider the former's characteristic polynomial:
$$p_{A_1}(x) = \det(xI-A_1) = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i) - \prod_{i=2}^n(x-\alpha_i)\sum_{i=2}^n\dfrac{b_i^2}{x-\alpha_i} = f(x)\left(x-\alpha-\sum_{i=2}^n\dfrac{b_i^2}{x-\alpha_i}\right)$$
with the notation $\alpha = \alpha_1$ and $\text{diag}(\alpha_i) = \text{diag}(\alpha_2,\ldots ,\alpha_n)$ and $f(x) = (x-\alpha_2)\ldots (x-\alpha_n),$ which is simply due to the Laplace expansion formula along the first row. So one also has:
$$p_{A_1+B_1}(x) = f(x)\left(x-\alpha-\rho-\sum_{i=2}^n\dfrac{b_i^2}{x-\alpha_i}\right).$$

Now the conclusion should follow almost immediately. First, note that $\dfrac{b_i^2}{x-\alpha_i}$ is simply a notational convenience, since it is not defined at $x = \alpha_i.$ Second, if $A_1$ had an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity greater than $1,$ then $p_{A_1+B_1}$ also has $\lambda$ as it's eigenvalue with multiplicity one less than the former, so we have:
$$\lambda_{A+B} = \lambda_A + m_i\rho$$
with $m_i = 0.$ So let's only focus on simple eigenvalues from now on (this implies $\alpha_i$ cannot be an eigenvalue). If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then (and assue WLOG $\rho > 0$):
$$\dfrac{p_{A_1+B_1}(\lambda)}{f(\lambda)} = -\rho <0$$ and
$$\dfrac{p_{A_1+B_1}(\lambda+\rho)}{f(\lambda+\rho)} = \lambda-\alpha-\sum_{i=2}^n\dfrac{b_i^2}{\lambda+\rho-\alpha_i} = \sum_{i=2}^n\left(\dfrac{b_i^2}{\lambda-\alpha_i}-\dfrac{b_i^2}{\lambda+\rho-\alpha_i}\right)>0.$$
Therefore, $p_{A_1+B_1}(\mu) = 0$ for some $\mu\in(\lambda, \lambda+\rho),$ which you can write as $\mu = \lambda + m\rho$ for some $m\in(0,1).$ This and the part about repeated eigenvalues finish the conclusion if you observe that:
$$\text{Tr}(A_1+B_1) = \text{Tr}(A_1) + \rho.$$

Note: The solution isn't written perfectly here. Specifically, the notation short hand:
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{x-\alpha_i} = \prod_{j=2, j\neq i}(x-\alpha_j)$$ could probably be made better.

Comment: This is such a great argument! One thing I don't get is how you know that if $A_1$ has an eigenvalue with multiplicity above one then $A_1+B_1$ has the same eigenvalue but with multiplicity less one?

Comment: @MonteNero I found it it's explained more succinctly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320509/two-matrices-that-are-not-similar-have-almost-same-eigenvalues?noredirect=1&lq=1). Essentially, the polynomials :
$$\prod_{j\neq i}(x-\lambda_j)$$ 
will still have the linear factor $(x-\lambda_i)$ if $\lambda_i$ was repeated twice or more.

Comment: also - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality is a good reference it looks like.

Comment: Excellent answer! What is the relation of the formula you derived to the secular equation, e.g. as described in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3625609/443030

Comment: what is a secular equation ?